# Unable to execute function after JSON loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is the [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zeciG) that shows that when a `JSON` request completes, a name 'Antonio' appears. But jQuery function is not executing on it. Please make sure that `document.write` is a necessary function for me.

This is the code I wrote to get the name Antonio.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function gallery(json) {
  document.write('<span>'+json.feed.title.$t+'</span>');
}
</script>
<script src='http://www.antonio-bloggerever.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/summary/-/Creative?max-results=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=gallery'/>
```

Comment: Please include relevant code here.

Comment: You must add inside of `document.write` your jquery `click` function

Comment: @fsi but how can you explain through any pen or fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hfylu)

You are essentially trying to bind a click event to an element that's not there yet.
For dynamically added elements to the DOM use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

```
$('span').on('click', function(){
  alert('aaaa');
});
```

Comment: You mean use event delegation?

Comment: @JuanMendes, yea sorry couldn't think of it from the top of my head, been a long day :)

Comment: @user3647936 This is not the right answer. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fktIK  The only problem with your first pen is that you didn't include jQuery

Comment: @Stefan Consider reading my comments and deleting your answer. It doesn't make any sense. [`$().click` is just a shortcut for `$().on('click')`](http://api.jquery.com/click/). You have not added event delegation. You would have to listen on the document and pass in a selector for you to use delegation. The documentation says it like this: `This method is a shortcut for .on( "click", handler )`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have jQuery included. Add `jQuery` and it will work. Write this line in starting of your HTML.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @user3647936 now it's there before it was saying `$` is not defined.

Comment: @user3647936 please provide any relevant information.

Comment: @user3647936 This is the correct answer See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fktIK Stefan's answer doesn't make any sense. Your initial code did not include jQuery. I'm sure you didn't look at the console for errors. When I opened it, it said `$ not defined`